# zsh from /usr/local/bin/zsh doesn't recognize vendor-completions

Tags: zsh

I've built zsh from sources and installed it in `/usr/local/bin/zsh`. There was a packaged installation in `/usr/bin/zsh` as well.

Now, when I install some other packages they occasionally put their completion file into `/usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions/_toolname`. The problem is that my custom zsh does not recognize those files. I tried to make symlinks to those files into `/usr/local/share/zsh/vendor-completions` (I had to create the directory as well) but had no success.

While building zsh I simply run `./configure` script, so `PREFIX` remained unchanged (and it is `/usr/local`) by default.

How to make vendor-completions work in my case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Completions are loaded from directories from `fpath` array. So directory `/usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions` must be explicitly included in it:

```
# do it before 'compinit' in ~/.zshrc
fpath=($fpath /usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions)
```

I still have no idea why it wasn't included by default.